# Extend JModel in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible somehow to add few my own methods to `JModel / JModelLegacy` without changing source code? For example from controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly add it into `JModel / JModelLegacy` then no.

If you building a component then yes as you extend `JControllerLegacy / JController` when you build your component in the controller.php file. But that will be specific to your component of course. It can't be used by another component